# how to add a button in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

Tell me how to add a button in android. And when we clicks on it it has to do a activity

Comment: new page?? whats a page. Do you mean activity.

Comment: buy and read a book, and read some tutorials.  if you don't know how to add a button and launch an activity, there are TONS of things you need to acquaint yourself with as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two articles should help you get started:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

and

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Download sample app from developer.android.com and start to play with it.